# Cg Code in Latex

Tags: highlighting, code

I am writing some document which contains Cg (C for Graphics) code in the document. I want to show the code in a neat highlighted mode. Any easy method to suggest? I tried the listings package but it doesn't support Cg language.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Cg, adding additional keywords to listings starting from, e.g., C, is not very difficult. I think to a zeroth approximation, a key like morekeywords={foo,bar,baz} might work, but better check the manual.

Comment: OK, I found the solution. It is similar to your suggestion. Check my answer :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I found the solution to my own question. I defined the Cg language using the following code:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{cg}{
    morekeywords={void, float, float2, float4, float4,
        float4x4, POSITION, TEXCOORD0, out, uniform},
    morecomment=[l]{//}
}
```

Some notes:
 1. The 'morekeywords' specify the keywords of the language. Obviously, there are many more keywords in the Cg language, but I used the ones I need.
 2. The 'morecomment' is used to specify commenting styles in the language. Cg language use the same style as C language.

Then I used the following code to make some customization:

```
\lstset{
    language=cg,
    tabsize=2,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{green}\scriptsize,
    stringstyle=\color{green},
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true
}
```

Finally, including my code in the document:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=cg]{VertexProgram.cg}
```

Don't forget to include the listings package:

```
\usepackage{listings}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice find, and +1 for being considerate enough to answer your own question for others :)